# Always show inbox on folder view Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I click on folder view in Outlook 2016 I get the right view of my "Inbox".
If I switch now to the calendar view and back to the folder view it does rest on calendar and I see a small calendar on the left.

How can I change this to show always the "Inbox" on folder view?
And is there a registry parameter for that?

Thank you!

[Screenshot(German Outlook version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7ZEo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Inbox is available in "Mail" and "Folders" views only.